# how to fire event from native module

Tags: java, android, titanium, titanium-modules

### CLI version 3.2.3, Titanium SDK version 3.2.2.GA

I am using a external jar file and trying to make it work into the native module so that native module can be used with titanium

i am not able to fire an event from the handler

i have two classes in native module 
clsModule  and Handler

#### clsModule.java

```
import ext.Extclient;

@Kroll.module(name="extclient", id="ti.extclient")
public class clsModule extends KrollModule{

private Handler h ;
Extclient ext ;

public clsModule()
    {
    super();
    ext = new Extclient();
     h = new Handler(this);
    im.addHandler(h);
    }
}
```

#### Handler.java

```
import ext.ResponseHandler;

public class Handler implements ResponseHandler 
    {

public void OnConnected(String arg0, String arg1) {
HashMap<String, Object> event = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    event.put("u1", arg0);
    event.put("u2", arg1);

    //How do i fire a event here ?

    }
}
```

i tried with fireEvent but that did not work it gives a error that it is not defined.

Comment: still looking for a solution ?

Comment: Did you try with Ti.App.fireEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module (as do all modules) extends [KrollModule](http://builds.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/javadoc/org/appcelerator/kroll/KrollModule.html) which extends [KrollProxy](http://builds.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/javadoc/org/appcelerator/kroll/KrollProxy.html), which handles events. Your Handler class does not have access to this object so it cannot fire the event itself, however you are already passing that reference (`new Handler(this)`) so just use it!

```
import ext.ResponseHandler;

public class Handler implements ResponseHandler {
    private KrollModule proxy; // Hold onto this reference
    public Handler(KrollModule proxy) {
        this.proxy = proxy;
    }

    public void OnConnected(String arg0, String arg1) {
        // Fire event if anyone is listening
        if (proxy.hasListeners("colorChange")) {
            HashMap<String, Object> event = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            event.put("u1", arg0);
            event.put("u2", arg1);
            proxy.fireEvent("colorChange", hm);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the general idea, pass the proxy to fire an event to the class itself, an alternative would be to inline an anonymous implementation of `ResponseHandler` inside your module instead. I'm not sure if you are implementing ResponseHandler right, or if `OnConnected` is even firing, you need to check that first.